# How to pretty print to a file in sympy?

Tags: python, file-io, sympy, pprint

Suppose I have the following code:

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.physics.quantum import TensorProduct

s=sp.eye(2)
a=TensorProduct(s*x,TensorProduct(s,s)).subs(x,x**2+2*x+1)
sp.pprint(a)
```

The code will generate an output with a limited widths (which I hate):

[image]

My questions are:

1. Why there is a width limit while my window has enough space and how to change it?
2. How to print such an output to a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `python>=3.4`,

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import sympy as sp
from sympy.physics.quantum import TensorProduct

s = sp.eye(2)
x = sp.symbols('x')
a = TensorProduct(s*x, TensorProduct(s, s)).subs(x, x**2+2*x+1)

with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        sp.pprint(a, wrap_line=False)
```

.

Answer (score 0):

[`sympy.preview`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html#preview):

```
sp.preview(a, viewer='file', filename="out.png", dvioptions=['-D','300'])
```

Would allow you to save the expression as LaTeX/png/pdf.